# Change Flickity groupCell options on larger screens

Tags: javascript, carousel, flickity

I want to change the Flickity groupCells options on a larger screen?

On mobile Flickity is showing one slide at a time, which is what I wish to keep. However, when the screen is larger, tablet and above I would like two slides to appear side by side.

I thought I should be able to achieve this by using `if ( matchMedia`, but have been unsuccessful.

Flickity Options

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // SLIDER

  $('.story-carousel').flickity({
    freeScroll: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    contain: true,
    autoPlay: 8000,
    pageDots: false,
    arrowShape: { 
      x0: 10,
      x1: 60, y1: 50,
      x2: 60, y2: 0,
      x3: 60
    }
  });

  // Change when larger screen is loaded
  if ( matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 769px)').matches ) {
    groupCells = true;
  }

  // Change when larger screen is loaded
  if ( matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 769px)').matches ) {
    groupCells = 2;
  }


});
```

I also tried…

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // SLIDER

  $('.story-carousel').flickity({
    // groupCells = true,
    // groupCells = 2,
    freeScroll: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    contain: true,
    autoPlay: 8000,
    pageDots: false,
    arrowShape: { 
      x0: 10,
      x1: 60, y1: 50,
      x2: 60, y2: 0,
      x3: 60
    }

  });

  // Flickity options, defaults
  var options = {
    groupCells: false,
    groupCells: 1,
  };

  // Change when larger screen is loaded
  if ( matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 768px)').matches ) {
    options.groupCells = true;
    options.groupCells = 2;
  }


  $('.gallery').flickity( options );

});
```

This is based on Desandro's comment on [GitHub](https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/233). However, also unsuccessful?

On desktop I am currently seeing…

[image]

But want this…

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Managed to get this working with the following code:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){

  // SLIDER

  $('.story-carousel').flickity({
    freeScroll: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    contain: true,
    autoPlay: 8000,
    pageDots: false,
    arrowShape: { 
      x0: 10,
      x1: 60, y1: 50,
      x2: 60, y2: 0,
      x3: 60
    }

  });

  // Default state
  if ( matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 768px)').matches ) {

    $('.story-carousel').flickity({
      groupCells: false,
      groupCells: 1,
    });

  }

  // // Change when larger screen is loaded
  if ( matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 769px)').matches ) {

    $('.story-carousel').flickity({
      groupCells: true,
      groupCells: 2,
    });

  }

});
```

Obviously any improvements would be welcome